# Unable to configure my App ID in iPhone developer portal

Tags: iphone, configure

Iam able to create a new apple ID from the provisioning portal from manage tab. But it always shows the app ID as unavailable for Push notification service. Action is to view the details.
When i click on that it says, 
""Note: Only explicit App IDs can be used to access the Apple Push Notification service. Please use an existing App ID with a specific Bundle Identifier or create a new one.""

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Ricardo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

Generic App ID containing `*` can't be used for push notification. For example, you can not use com.yourcompany.* for APN as it contains `*`. The main thing is for APN and In App Purchase, you can not use single app id for more than one app.